# rDNS multiple IPs same interface

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, hostname, reverse-dns

I have three different IPs on the same interface:

```
eth0      192.168.1.103
eth0:0    192.168.1.104
eth0:1    192.168.1.105
```

and I have the following in `/etc/hosts:`

```
192.168.1.103  host.example.com  host
192.168.1.104  host.example.com  host
192.168.1.105  host.example.com  host
```

Now, I'm wondering what are the proper entries for my `192.168.1.rev`, so far I have it as:

```
103 IN PTR host.example.com.
104 IN PTR host.example.com.
105 IN PTR host.example.com.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the correct structure, although you'll probably want to put trailing dots on the rrdata so it doesn't append the zone name (`host.example.com.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa`).